# How to get the ROOT node name from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have a table where `ID` is `integer` and `XML` is `XML` data type.

```
ID   XML
----------------------
1    <Form1>...</Form1>
2    <Form1>...</Form1>
3    <Form2>...</Form2>
4    <Form3>...</Form3>
```

How do I get the result below?

```
ID   XML
-------------
1    Form1
2    Form1
3    Form2
4    Form3
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the `local-name()` function

```
 select ID, XML.value('local-name(/*[1])','varchar(100)')
 from yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @xml as xml
SET @xml = '<Form1>...</Form1>'
SELECT Nodes.Name.query('local-name(.)') FROM @xml.nodes('//*') As Nodes(Name)
```

Comment: We were using this method, but we ran into issues with "local-name(.)" being a slow operation.  replacing the . with /*[1] as indicated in the above answer gave us better performance.